# Is there is any way to pass the timeout value for aws lambda function programmatically?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, timeout, aws-lambda, snapshot

I am working on getting snapshot API using aws lambda. I wan to pass the timeout value for lambda function  depends on number of snapshots to be taken. So, Is there is any way to pass the timeout value to aws function runtime?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cannot set the timeout function dynamically for each invocation. Is there a reason you aren't just setting the timeout high, and relying on the function to properly exit when it is finished?

Comment: setting the high timeout is one solution but I am checking if we can pass timeout dynamically then its better one

Comment: looks like aws lambda dosen't provide such feature

Comment: You can't set it dynamically. I'm not sure how it would be better in any way. Do you want Lambda to possibly kill off your function before it is finished running?

Comment: no I want to increase timeout if number of screenshots are increased too much than my expectation then also my function should handle it rather than getting timed-out